# complex hex numbers in C

Tags: c

Is there an option to store a hex complex number in c?

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Read strings....

Comment: There's a trick to seeing if a number is divisible by 3. You can do that without having to convert those numbers.

Comment: take input as a character array

Comment: So you are to return "true" if the modulo 3 of the sum is 0?

Answer (score 3):

The remainder of a number divided by 3 equals to the sum of its digits modulo 3.

Once you calculate the remainders for the two numbers (not need to represent each number's value), sum those. If result modulo 3 is zero, the sum of the number is a multiplication of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess you are not getting the problem. Rather getting the input is easier but processing it is not.

So no type would be big enough to accurately hold the value - these are large. Why not store it as string?

You can store it as a char array and use `fgets` for that (this is only if you want to print the number otherwise not needed). You can use `getchar()` also and do the sum as shown in the proof here.

After doing it, just do one thing - check each digit-char and then calculate it's sum mod 3. That way you will get the value of the result and keep it adding. (The resultant  mod sum tells you about the divisibility). That is what you want exactly.

#### What I meant is?

```
  (A + B) mod 3 

= (   A(n)A(n-1)A(n-2)...A(1)A(0)
  +   B(m)B(m-1)B(m-2)...B(1)B(0) ) mod 3 

= ( [ A(n) + A(n-1) + A(n-2) + ... + A(1) + A(0) ] mod 3
  + [ B(m) + B(m-1) + B(m-2) + ... + B(1) + B(0) ] mod 3 ) mod 3
```

Rules:

```
if a≡b (mod m) and c≡d (mod m) then

a+c ≡ b+d (mod m) and
 ac ≡ bd (mod m)
```

#### Example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int c,sum = 0;
    while(isdigit(c = getchar()))
        sum+=(c-'0'),sum%=3;
    while(isdigit(c = getchar()))
        sum+=(c-'0'),sum%=3;
    printf("%s\n", sum?"Non-divisible":"divisible");
    return 0;
}
```